# What is the best way to copy a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I want to make a copy of a database, I always create a new empty database, and then restore a backup of the existing database into it. However, I'm wondering if this is really the least error-prone, least complicated, and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup and Restore is the most straight-forward way I know.  You have to be careful between servers as security credentials don't come with the restored database.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to skip the step of creating the empty database. You can create the new database as part of the restore process.

This is actually the easiest and best way I know of to clone a database. You can eliminate errors by scripting the backup and restore process rather than running it through the SQL Server Management Studio

There are two other options you could explore:

1. Detach the database, copy the .mdf file and re-attach.
2. Use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to copy all the objects over

I suggest sticking with backup and restore and automating if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dynamic sql script I've used in the past.  It can be further modified but it will give you the basics.  I prefer scripting it to avoid the mistakes you can make using the Management Studio:

```
Declare @OldDB varchar(100)
Declare @NewDB varchar(100)
Declare @vchBackupPath varchar(255)
Declare @query varchar(8000)


/*Test code to implement 
Select @OldDB = 'Pubs'
Select @NewDB = 'Pubs2'
Select @vchBackupPath = '\\dbserver\C$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\pubs.bak'
*/

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Select @query = 'Create Database ' + @NewDB
exec(@query)

Select @query = '
Declare @vBAKPath varchar(256)
declare @oldMDFName varchar(100)
declare @oldLDFName varchar(100)
declare @newMDFPath varchar(100)
declare @newLDFPath varchar(100)
declare @restQuery varchar(800)

select @vBAKPath = ''' + @vchBackupPath + '''
select @oldLDFName = name from ' + @OldDB +'.dbo.sysfiles where filename like ''%.ldf%''
select @oldMDFName = name from  ' + @OldDB +'.dbo.sysfiles where filename like ''%.mdf%''
select @newMDFPath = physical_name from ' + @NewDB +'.sys.database_files where type_desc = ''ROWS''
select @newLDFPath = physical_name from ' + @NewDB +'.sys.database_files where type_desc = ''LOG''

select @restQuery = ''RESTORE DATABASE ' + @NewDB + 
' FROM DISK = N'' + '''''''' + @vBAKpath + '''''''' + 
'' WITH MOVE N'' + '''''''' + @oldMDFName + '''''''' +  
'' TO N'' + '''''''' + @newMDFPath + '''''''' +  
'', MOVE N'' + '''''''' + @oldLDFName + '''''''' +  
'' TO N'' + '''''''' + @newLDFPath + '''''''' +  
'', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10''

exec(@restQuery)
--print @restQuery'


exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Publish to Provider** functionality has worked great for me.  See [Scott Gu's Blog Entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx).

If you need something really robust look  at redgate software's tools [here](http://www.red-gate.com/)...if you are doing much SQL at all, these are worth the $$.

Answer (score 0):

```
::================ BackUpAllMyDatabases.cmd ============= START
::BackUpAllMyDatabases.cmd
:: COMMAND LINE BATCH SCRIPT FOR TAKING BACKUP OF ALL DATABASES 

::RUN THE SQL SCRIPT VIA THE COMMAND LINE WITH LOGGING 
sqlcmd -S localhost -e  -i "BackUpAllMyDatabases.sql" -o Result_Of_BackUpAllMyDatabases.log

::VIEW THE RESULTS
Result_Of_BackUpAllMyDatabases.log

::pause
::================ BackUpAllMyDatabases.cmd ============= END


--=================================================BackUpAllMyDatabases.sql start
DECLARE @DBName varchar(255)

DECLARE @DATABASES_Fetch int

DECLARE DATABASES_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    select
        DATABASE_NAME   = db_name(s_mf.database_id)
    from
        sys.master_files s_mf
    where
       -- ONLINE
        s_mf.state = 0 

       -- Only look at databases to which we have access
    and has_dbaccess(db_name(s_mf.database_id)) = 1 

        -- Not master, tempdb or model
    --and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not in ('Master','tempdb','model')
    group by s_mf.database_id
    order by 1

OPEN DATABASES_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM DATABASES_CURSOR INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    declare @DBFileName varchar(256)    
    set @DBFileName = @DbName + '_' + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112), '-', '.') + '.bak'
--REMEMBER TO PUT HERE THE TRAILING \ FOR THE DIRECTORY !!!
    exec ('BACKUP DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] TO  DISK = N''D:\DATA\BACKUPS\' + 
        @DBFileName + ''' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N''' + 
        @DBName + '-Full Database Backup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 100')

    FETCH NEXT FROM DATABASES_CURSOR INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE DATABASES_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DATABASES_CURSOR

--BackUpAllMyDatabases==========================end

--======================RestoreDbFromFile.sql start
-- Restore database from file
-----------------------------------------------------------------
use master
go

declare @backupFileName varchar(100), @restoreDirectory varchar(100),
@databaseDataFilename varchar(100), @databaseLogFilename varchar(100),
@databaseDataFile varchar(100), @databaseLogFile varchar(100),
@databaseName varchar(100), @execSql nvarchar(1000)

-- Set the name of the database to restore
set @databaseName = 'ReplaceDataBaseNameHere'
-- Set the path to the directory containing the database backup
set @restoreDirectory = 'ReplaceRestoreDirectoryHere' -- such as 'c:\temp\'

-- Create the backup file name based on the restore directory, the database name and today's date

@backupFileName = @restoreDirectory + @databaseName + '-' + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 110), '-', '.') + '.bak'


-- set @backupFileName = 'D:\DATA\BACKUPS\server.poc_test_fbu_20081016.bak'

-- Get the data file and its path
select @databaseDataFile = rtrim([Name]),
@databaseDataFilename = rtrim([Filename])
from master.dbo.sysaltfiles as files
inner join
master.dbo.sysfilegroups as groups
on

files.groupID = groups.groupID
where DBID = (
select dbid
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
where [Name] = @databaseName
)

-- Get the log file and its path
select @databaseLogFile = rtrim([Name]),
@databaseLogFilename = rtrim([Filename])
from master.dbo.sysaltfiles as files
where DBID = (
select dbid
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
where [Name] = @databaseName
)
and
groupID = 0

print 'Killing active connections to the "' + @databaseName + '" database'

-- Create the sql to kill the active database connections
set @execSql = ''
select @execSql = @execSql + 'kill ' + convert(char(10), spid) + ' '
from master.dbo.sysprocesses
where db_name(dbid) = @databaseName
and
DBID <> 0
and
spid <> @@spid
exec (@execSql)

print 'Restoring "' + @databaseName + '" database from "' + @backupFileName + '" with '
print ' data file "' + @databaseDataFile + '" located at "' + @databaseDataFilename + '"'
print ' log file "' + @databaseLogFile + '" located at "' + @databaseLogFilename + '"'

set @execSql = '
restore database [' + @databaseName + ']
from disk = ''' + @backupFileName + '''
with
file = 1,
move ''' + @databaseDataFile + ''' to ' + '''' + @databaseDataFilename + ''',
move ''' + @databaseLogFile + ''' to ' + '''' + @databaseLogFilename + ''',
norewind,
nounload,
replace'

exec sp_executesql @execSql

exec('use ' + @databaseName)
go

-- If needed, restore the database user associated with the database
/*
exec sp_revokedbaccess 'myDBUser'
go

exec sp_grantdbaccess 'myDBUser', 'myDBUser'
go

exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'myDBUser'
go

use master
go
*/
--======================RestoreDbFromFile.sql
```